# Intellij does not support dslr files

Tags: drools

I am new to drools. I was trying to write a DSLR file using the IntelliJ idea. But it seem to be not supporting .dslr files as it supports .drl files. How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't think any plugin can support a DSL format as the syntax is defined by the DSL. It is, more or less, only rule <name> when - then - end, with "anything" in the gaps ("-"). Just use a simple text editor.